# Is $x^{2a}+y^{2b}=1$ diffeomorphic to the circle ($x^2+y^2=1$)?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, can you find (and prove that it is what it is) an explicit diffeomorphism between $$M_{a,b}:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^{2a}+y^{2b}=1\}$$ and the usual circle $S:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$?
Of course, these manifolds are equipped with the unique smooth structure that derives from seeing them as regular levels sets of functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$.

This is a question inspired by Problem 5-1 of Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $C_{a,b}$ the curve $x^{2a} + y^{2b} = 1$. Let's show that the central projection map from $C_{a,b}$ to another curve $C_{c,d}$ is smooth.  Indeed, $(x,y) \in R^{2} \backslash \{(0,0)\}$  maps to $r(x,y)\cdot (x,y)$, where $r = r(x,y)$ is such that
$$r^{2c} x^{2c} + r^{2 d} y^{2d} = 1$$
Now, for given $u$, $v$ positive, not both $0$, there exists a unique $r>0$ such that
$$r^{2c} u + r^{2d} v = 1$$
and $r$ depends smoothly on $(u,v)$ (implicit function theorem).